# Android Thing IMX7D boota: no bootable slot

Tags: android, android-things

Hi everyone i recently get a IMX7D android thing board.i has some trouble flash the image. thank anyone who can give me some advise
i run with the window
first i use mfgtool 
run mfgtool2-brillo-mx7d-pico-emmc.vbs
the result seem ok.
then i download the android thing image 
i just run the flash-all.bat

----------------------------Hear is My Err Message------------------------------

```
target reported max download size of 419430400 bytes
sending 'bootloader0' (559 KB)...
OKAY [  0.033s]
writing 'bootloader0'...
FAILED (remote: partition does not exist)
finished. total time: 0.264s
target reported max download size of 419430400 bytes
sending 'bootloader' (559 KB)...
OKAY [  0.027s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  0.252s]
finished. total time: 0.285s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.007s]
finished. total time: 0.009s
target reported max download size of 419430400 bytes
sending 'gpt' (33 KB)...
OKAY [  0.006s]
writing 'gpt'...
OKAY [  0.440s]
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.008s]
finished. total time: 0.465s
target reported max download size of 419430400 bytes
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 1930952704
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 7872
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 7366
    Label:
    Blocks: 471424
    Block groups: 15
    Reserved block group size: 119
Created filesystem with 11/118080 inodes and 15505/471424 blocks
Slot a does not exist. supported slots are:
_a
_b
```

Comment: What version are you trying to flash? And did you have any versions on this board previously?

Answer (score 0):

This is typically caused by using an incompatible version of `fastboot` on your machine. I would recommend using the Android Things Setup Utility (as described in the [i.MX7D Setup Docs](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d.html)) instead of the `flash-all` script. This utility will download and manage the proper version of `fastboot` for you automatically.