# My other imx7d pico android things start kit died, again

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, android-things, mender

1) I had this problem with my imx7d-pico SOM module: https://community.nxp.com/message/1228990

I tried to buy another module (only) and/or get technical support, but Technexion claimed that as a physical person I could not purchase another module directly. This company blocked me, even on github. I did nothing wrong. I just asked for support.

2) A colleague sold me a new imx7d-pico android things kit.

3) On this second SOM/Carrier board I had the same problem as with the first. I'll talk about it below:

3.a -> As attached image named issuetoda, I had been trying to upload yocto on this device. I got the error: **boota: no bootable slot**, because instead of using dfu 0 mmc 1, I used dfu 0 mmc 0:

I went to my computer with W10 (one USB 2.0 and one USB 3.0) and mfgtools configured to erase the data using the mfgtool2-brillo-mx7d-pico-emmc-firmware command. And this was done, as per photo name: screenissue

3.c -> The screenissue image have a question 1 is:  I left this screen (with green stripes and finished service from image screenissue) for 8 minutes at a standstill. Because I went for coffee. Of course, it is at this point (or, instantly after I clicked STOP/EXIT that the problem occurred. (Both this SOM module and the one that blew it).

question 1 is: **Why did this (8-minute delay) procedure damaged my device?**

3.d -> The screenissue image have a questions 2 is: Whats is out55 the USB-OTG cable? Where I find picture of it?

I bought a cable with TRS and female usb otg connector, coupled with a male -> male usb cable and plugged it into the i2s audio input on the carrier board. But it did not solve the problem.

4) I tried everything in links below, but not solved:

https://developer.solid-run.com/knowledge-base/efuses-for-imx6-som-developers-page/

https://www.technexion.com/support/knowledgebase/loading-bootable-software-images-onto-the-emmc-of-picosom-on-pico-pi/

**Can anyone help me?**

[image][image]

Comment: Possibly also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995111/android-thing-imx7d-boota-no-bootable-slot - almost certainly off topic.

Comment: Clifford  @Clifford friend, you are wrong. I posted the error screen (which by the way is easy and I can fix it) just to tell the story of the last thing I did with the SOM/carrier board still working. My problem is bricked SOM module (or fuse), more serious and hard to fix

Comment: https://github.com/TechNexion/imx-mfgtools-tn/issues/1#issuecomment-552164634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Unfortunately the solution to this issue has not come yet, as links below:

https://community.nxp.com/message/1254248

https://community.nxp.com/message/1249782
)
I found out what bricked my device. In this link: https://community.nxp.com/thread/452013 (stepes 1 to 5) I used the mfgtool2-brillo-mx7d-multa-emmc-firmware script instead of the mfgtool2-brillo-mx7d-pico-emmc-firmware script. The mfgtool2-brillo-mx7d-multa-emmc-firmware script have a command ""eMMC-Brillo-uboot-fuse"" (look pic below...

[image]